# How to write a Batch file to go to the directory mentioned in a variable inside for loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How to write a Batch file to go to the directory mentioned in a variable inside for loop.

I have the below query which allows me to select a file through the file select dialog and I have placed the directory of the file in variable path1.

I need to go to this directory and then again create a folder there with the user input name.

I am writing the below code but echo !mypath! is showing the directory where the batch file is present.

```
<# : chooser.bat
:: launches a File 

@echo off


for /f "delims=" %%I in ('powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"') do (
    echo You chose %%~dpI >> E:\Rajan\test.txt

set "path1=%%~dpI"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !path1! >> E:\Rajan\test2.txt

cd /D "!path1!"

set /p name =Enter your name
set mypath=%cd%
echo !mypath! >> E:\Rajan\test3.txt
md "%name%"
endlocal
)
goto :EOF 

: #>

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$f = new-object Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$f.InitialDirectory = pwd
$f.Filter = "Text Files (*.dmp)|*.dmp"
$f.ShowHelp = $true
$f.Multiselect = $false
[void]$f.ShowDialog()
if ($f.Multiselect) { $f.FileNames } else { $f.FileName }
```

Comment: cd /D "!path1" ... is this intended or cd /D "!path1!".  After that fails, you are setting the directory to %cd%.  Take away the @echo off command and LOOK at what it is doing.  I hope you are testing this from the command prompt and not by double clicking the file.  That is the closest to a debugger batch will give you.

Comment: Why did you delete your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64599498), where I had answered with a method of doing exactly what you're still proposing? Am I supposed to post [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64600110/6738015) again? or are you simply not interested?

Comment: @Compo the answer posted by you tells about using a JScript invoked folder browser instead of a PowerShell invoked file browser and it doesn't answers my Question

Comment: @RajanSinha, the method of creating the dialog box, is irrelevant to your question, what you wanted, and have asked for again, is a method of using the selected directory from the dialog box, within a `for` loop, and that is what that answer provides! If there was something in particular wrong with my understanding of what you were trying to achieve, you should have provided acceptable feedback, instead of just deleting the question. Don't expect a community to help you, when you clearly don't want to embrace being an integral part of it.

Comment: No grudges, but I really want my answer in cmd only. Due to some reasons, I can't use javascript (as I don't have much understanding of it and due to some security reasons I can't use JS).

I want to help the community too but my questions get closed without any strong reasons (even though I write full code and thses type of questions can really help others, especially begineers like me)

Comment: @Señor CMasMas, Yes I corrected the typo. I am only running these by double clicking batch files

Comment: @Compo isn't wrong (he *almost* never is).. using the windows scripting host will work on ANY post XP machine and it is WAY SIMPLE.  Powershell has many features that are complicated by changing in each version Microsoft produces and limited by security until you allow scripts to run in such a way.  Compo merely picked the right tool for the job.

Comment: Also in your [DELETED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64599498/batch-file-to-go-to-directory-mentioned-in-variable-inside-for-loop) question, I had all kinds of comments that told you what was wrong with your code and you didn't even bother to make changes to this question to reflect those comments.

Comment: In your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64594739/6738015), which was also closed, for good reason, you were still unsatisfied the reasons for my sugested closure, and felt in comment that an answer was useful to future readers. Therefore, to show you, and future readers, that the solution was clearly outlined within the help information for your command, I posted an answer. You did not respond to it, provide feedback, upvote it, or mark it as accepted. How does that type of behavior support your comment above, which states, "I want to help the community"?

Comment: @RajanSinha, given that around 2½ hours have elapsed since you last logged in, that no comment has been made by you here, or in that last question, no edit has been made to your question code to encompass the advice given in your previous questions, and that no answer has been marked as accepted here or in your previous question. Is there something you're still struggling with understanding?

Answer (score 1):

I thought I put this on the previous question.

```
<# : chooser.bat
:: launches a File 

@echo off
SET "THE_FILE="
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"') do (
    echo You chose %%~I
    SET "THE_FILE=%%~I"
)

CD /D "%THE_FILE%\..\"

set /p "name=Enter your name: "
set "mypath=%cd%"
echo %mypath% >>"E:\Rajan\test3.txt"
IF NOT EXIST ".\%name%" (md "%name%")
goto :EOF

: #>

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$f = new-object Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$f.InitialDirectory = pwd
$f.Filter = "Text Files (*.dmp)|*.dmp"
$f.ShowHelp = $true
$f.Multiselect = $false
[void]$f.ShowDialog()
if ($f.Multiselect) { $f.FileNames } else { $f.FileName }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer again, this time using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell), instead of [jscript](/questions/tagged/jscript), to invoke the dialog box.

```bsh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('^"
    "%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile ^
     "(New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application').BrowseForFolder(0,'Select your directory.',1,0).Self.Path"
^"') Do MD "%%G\%UserName%"
```

As you can clearly see, the command using the output from the [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) is exactly as I provided in my previous answer, and shows [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64649831/how-to-write-a-batch-file-to-go-to-the-directory-mentioned-in-a-variable-inside?noredirect=1#comment114311378_64649831), to be correct.